# Difference of differences

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

Let's take a series:

A: a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub> a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>

Let's say the standard deviation of the above series is S<sub>1</sub>

Now let's create B = b<sub>1</sub> b<sub>2</sub> ... b<sub>n</sub> such that b<sub>x</sub> = a<sub>x+1</sub> - a<sub>x</sub> The standard deviation of B = S<sub>2</sub>

Similarly if we create a series C, D,.. so on with standard deviations S<sub>3</sub>, S<sub>4</sub>.. so on.

This creates another series S: S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub> ...

So I have two questions:

1. What is the significance of C, D, E... series. Is there any practical or theoretical usage of this?
2. What is the significance of series S. Is there any practical or theoretical usage of this?

Answer (score 0):

With A as the original series, then B is the first derivative, C the 2nd derivative, D the third derivative, etc. This has many uses depending on the type of data you look at.

If $a_i$ were positional data aquired from your GPS, then the $b_i$ were your velocity, and the $c_i$ your acceleration, $d_i$ the change of acceleration.

The values of $S_i$ may have a meaning e. g. as judgement for noise (especially for periodic or quasi static processes) or not, depending on the type of data and their meaning.